# Where should an objects' associated objects be restored when using the table data gateway pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, zend-framework2, poeaa

I have a class `User` which has the property `address` which is an instance of `Address`. I am using the [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) pattern to manage the persistence of the `User` object.

Assuming the `Address` class has its own Table Gateway, who should be responsible for setting the `User`'s `address` property?

As an example of what I am asking in PHP:

```
<?php
$user = $userTableGateway->getUserWithId(5); // \My\Classes\User
$address = $user->address; // \My\Classes\Address  <-- Who makes sure this exists?
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "who?"  If I understand that pattern correctly, it's basically a CRUD object.  The object itself is responsible for setting values.

Comment: The object itself is responsible for restoring the state of other objects? That would violate the domain model pattern and the law of demeter. When I say who I mean where in the structure would be responsible for restoring the state of the associated object.

Comment: The Table Data Gateway maintains a *database table.*  The database table is what holds the state.  Are you sure you understand the pattern?  What does LOD have to do with anything?  Stop using buzzwords until you understand what they mean.

Comment: That's part of my question though, I understand the purpose of the table gateway but where in the code should be responsible for restoring the associated objects using the associated objects table gateway? Using a table gateway from within another table gateway doesn't seem right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47275/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-nathanjosiah)